# Unexpected results when applying convolution to variables created using rnorm?

Tags: r, convolution

I create two variables $x$ and $eps$ using the norm function and then convolve them to obtain a new variable $y$. When I plot the densities of $x, eps$, and $y$, however, there seems to be a problem with the $y$ density.

I have a very small variance on the eps variable, so I would expect the $y$ density to look alot like the $x$ density, because the convolution of $x$ and $eps$ is similar to the convolution between $x$ and a Dirac delta since the variance of eps is so small.

But instead I get a $y$ density that doesn't look much like $x$, nevermind that the scales of the $y$ plot are vastly different than the scales of the $x$ plot.

So what have I done wrong? How can I perform a convolution of $x$ and $eps$ correctly?

[image]

```
x_mean = 5
x_var = 2
x <- rnorm(200,x_mean,x_var)

eps_mean = 0
eps_var = 0.0001
eps <- rnorm(200,eps_mean,eps_var)

y <- convolve(x,eps)

windows()
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(density(x))
plot(density(eps))
plot(density(y))
```

Comment: I suspect you mistake what `convolve` does.  In particular, it does not convolve densities.  To determine what you might have done wrong, though, we would need to know what your statistical objective is.  Could you clarify and explain what you hope a "correct" convolution of $x$ and $\epsilon$ would do?

Comment: Essentially I was aiming to create random normally distributed data $x$ and normally distributed error eps, and then I wanted to convolve the probability density/mass functions of these variables.

Comment: Then you first need to estimate the densities from the samples (using a KDE that employs the same spacing among the values!) and convolve the KDEs.  What you are doing is unrelated to this (and has little statistical meaning).  Your example is unhelpful because the SD of `eps` is so tiny relative to that of `x` that the convolution will make no noticeable difference.  Test using variables with similar SDs.